# Use email and phone instead of username and password Oauth2 Yii2

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yii2, authorization

I have configure `outh2` in `yii2`. It is working fine for username and password but my requirement is to use `email` and `phone numbe`r instead of `username/password`. How can I do so it will work for email and phone number. 
Thank you

Comment: You would have to change code in `vendor` folder which is not a good idea. I don't find anywhere (and unlikely to be one) that allows to change which information to send to authenticate. Are you also ok with changing code in `vendor`?